# Non-normal distribution of residual errors in time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, distributions, normal-distribution, forecasting, residuals

My dataset consists of temperature measurements from thermocouples as shown in the figure.[image]

I use several models like Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) and GRU in order to predict future values of these thermocouples. Only past measurements of the thermocouples are taken into consideration in my model, no other variables. My RMSE and Mean Absolute Error values for all the models are acceptable. However, the residual errors do not follow normal distribution. The distribution of the errors is bimodal, where major mode is a gaussian distribution and minor mode is a lognormal distribution. Is it a requirement for a time series forecasting model to have residual errors that follow normal distribution? Does the non normal distribution of the residual errors show that we cannot trust the model?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. No, Normality is not required in time series models, but it may still be the case that the residual errors indicate that you cannot trust the model.  2. This looks like a piecewise linear function with three segments would fit extremely well; why are you using LSTM and GRU to fit it?

Comment: @jbowman thank you for your comment! We are just testing different ML models to see their performance.